# Should I gray scale the image?

Tags: opencv, neural-network, deep-learning, gpu, conv-neural-network

I'm categorizing 30 types of clothes from the image using R-CNN Object Detection Library from tensorflow : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

Does color matter when we collect images for training and testing?

If I put only purple and blue shirts, I guess it won't recognize red shirts?

Should I gray scale all images to detect the types of clothes? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, colour does matter. The underlying visual feature extraction is based on a convolutional neural network, pre-trained to perform image recognition on colour images in the ImageNet dataset.

The R-CNN repository instructions on [bringing in your own dataset](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md) asks for RGB images.

> Dataset Requirements
>
> For every example in your dataset, you should have the following information:
>
> 1. An RGB image for the dataset encoded as jpeg or png.
> 2. A list of bounding boxes for the image. Each bounding box should contain:
>
>    - A bounding box coordinates (with origin in top left corner) defined by 4 floating point numbers [ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax]. Note that we store the normalized coordinates (x / width, y / height) in the TFRecord dataset.
>    - The class of the object in the bounding box.

Comment: Cool. Do you think gray-scaling the image will solve this problem??

Comment: If you grayscale the images, then your bounding box classes are simply "hat", "blouse", "trousers", "dress", etc.

If you don't grayscale the images, the bounding box classes can either be the same, or they can be more fine-grained, e.g. "red hat", "white blouse", "green trousers", "polka dot dress".

Comment: Cool! That's what I wanted! Thanks!